# QfieldCloud Community

Tags: qgis, qfield-cloud

I have uploaded my project to QfieldCloud Community, but it does not show on the Community Project part.

Second, when I try the projects from the community, I am able to open them but not edit them, while according to the QfieldCloud website, public project collaboration is allowed.

Does anyone know what the problem is?